# Getting the value of key/value pair in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two files in an App Script project:

```
#Code.gs
function myFunction() {
  ksu = "Kansas State University";
  Logger.log(lgu_map[ksu]);
}

#data.gs
function lgu_map() {
  map["University of Arkansas Pine Bluff"] = "1890";
  map["University of Maryland Eastern Shore"] = "1890";
  map["Virginia State University"] = "1890";
  map["West Virginia State University"] = "1890";
  map["Iowa State University"] = "North Central";
  map["Kansas State University"] = "North Central";
  map["Michigan State University"] = "North Central";
  map["North Dakota State University"] = "North Central";
  map["Ohio State University    North"] = "Central";
}
```

What I am wanting to do is query the lgu_map() function in data.gs to return is value. So in this case, what I'm wanting `Logger.log(lgu_map[ksu]);` to return is `North Central`.

Not even sure if I can call the function with way without actually passing an argument.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You should review  [maps set usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("University of Arkansas Pine Bluff", "1890");
myMap.set("University of Maryland Eastern Shore", "1890");
myMap.set("Virginia State University", "1890");
myMap.set("West Virginia State University", "1890");
myMap.set("Iowa State University", "North Central");
myMap.set("Kansas State University", "North Central");
myMap.set("Michigan State University", "North Central");
myMap.set("North Dakota State University", "North Central");
myMap.set("Ohio State University    North", "Central");
myMap.get("University of Arkansas Pine Bluff");//1890
```

- [Javascript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you need no function nor map. It can be just a plain object (it should be placed outside of any functions as a global variable):

```js
// code.gs -------------------------------------------------

function myFunction() {
  ksu = "Kansas State University";
  console.log(lgu_map[ksu]);
}

// data.gs -------------------------------------------------

var lgu_map = {

  "University of Arkansas Pine Bluff"    : "1890",
  "University of Maryland Eastern Shore" : "1890",
  "Virginia State University"            : "1890",
  "West Virginia State University"       : "1890",
  "Iowa State University"                : "North Central",
  "Kansas State University"              : "North Central",
  "Michigan State University"            : "North Central",
  "North Dakota State University"        : "North Central",
  "Ohio State University    North"       : "Central",

}

myFunction(); // output --> 'North Central'
```

Comment: Yes, I think this would work also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks copper, the syntax I was using to create a map seemed to be the issue. I still ended up having to pass the key to the function; not sure there is a way around that. Here is the complete working code for what I was wanting to do:

```
#code.gs
function myFunction() {
  ksu = "Kansas State University";
  Logger.log(lgu_map(ksu));
}

#data.gs
function lgu_map(key) {
  const myMap = new Map();
  myMap.set("University of Arkansas Pine Bluff", "1890");
  myMap.set("University of Maryland Eastern Shore", "1890");
  myMap.set("Virginia State University", "1890");
  myMap.set("West Virginia State University", "1890");
  myMap.set("Iowa State University", "North Central");
  myMap.set("Kansas State University", "North Central");
  myMap.set("Michigan State University", "North Central");
  myMap.set("North Dakota State University", "North Central");
  myMap.set("Ohio State University    North", "Central");
  return myMap.get(key);
```

}

Comment: In this situation since you can not store the object in global memory since it would be initialized repeatedly with every function cal, so it would probably be better to use PropertiesService.